# How to customize clustering in mclust?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the mclust package of R. I want to cluster some data.

Here are the steps to what I have done :

Reading data :

```
mydata <- read.table("\Users......", row.names= 1, sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

Using mclust : library(mclust)
mydataModel <- Mclust(mydata)
summary(mydataModel)
```

It breaks into 7 clusters. However, I want my data to be broken only into 2 clusters. Please help on how to do ?

Comment: Did you start by reading the `?Mclust` help page?? Try `mydataModel <- Mclust(mydata, 2)` and be sure to read the documentation for the functions you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MrFlick, you should read the documentation by adding a `?function()`.

In your case, do `?Mclust()` in your R console to see how default parameters have been set up.

This will show up once you do `?Mclust()`

```
Mclust(data, G = NULL, modelNames = NULL, 
       prior = NULL, 
       control = emControl(), 
       initialization = NULL, 
       warn = mclust.options("warn"), ...)
```

All you need to do is:
 `Mclust(mydata, 2)`